# Why is a template condition: not an instanceof CfnCondition?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm wondering why a condition in an AWS template is an instance of `software.amazon.awscdk.core.Construct` and not an instance of `CfnCondition`.

```
Conditions:
  ShouldCreateInfra: !Equals [!Ref CreateInfra, true]
  ShouldCreateDB: !Equals [!Ref CreateDB, true]
```

Given the java code:

```
CfnInclude template;
List<IConstruct> lic = template.getNode().getChildren();
for (IConstruct IC : lic) {
  LOG.debug("TemplateToTreeMap class name " + IC.getClass().getTypeName());
  if (IC instanceof CfnCondition) {
    LOG.debug("IC is instanceof of CfnCondition");
  }else if (IC instanceof CfnParameter) {
    LOG.debug("IC is instanceof of CfnParameter");
  }
}
```

When the construct is a template condition, it is an instance of `software.amazon.awscdk.core.Construct` rather than a `CfnCondition`, which differs from the case when the construct is a `CfnParameter` which is an instance of `CfnParameter`.

Both `CfnCondition` and `CfnParameter` extend `CfnElement`.

Why does that happen and how then do I identify a condition?

Alternatively I've tried as a work around the following:

```
if (IC.toString().contains("$Conditions")) {
    LOG.debug(IC.toString());
    Construct C = (Construct) IC;
    LOG.debug(toJsonString(C.getNode()));
    LOG.debug(stack.resolve(C).toString());
```

Which gives output as follows

```
AwsCdkStack/Template/$Conditions
${Token[TOKEN.646]}
```

But then results in an error

```
    software.amazon.jsii.JsiiException: 
Unable to resolve object tree with circular reference. Path: /node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node
Error: Unable to resolve object tree with circular reference. Path: /node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node/host/node
    at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:35:15)
    at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:29:33)
    at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:118:43)
    at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:29:33)
    at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:118:43)
    at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:29:33)
    at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:118:43)
    at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:29:33)
    at resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:118:43)
    at Object.resolve (/tmp/jsii-kernel-w8xgCb/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/private/resolve.js:29:33)
    at com.iriusrisk.cfimport.BasicApplicationTests.Example1_1(BasicApplicationTests.java:29)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the CfnCondition use the following

```
CfnCondition condition = this.template.getCondition(condition_name);
```